# OpenCv cv2.bitwise_or operation in python while using google collab

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I want to make a or operation with two images one of them. First image is white_background and second image is my mask what ı want to put on the white background , al of these for getting black and white img without using color map. ı am using Google Collab

Imag loading part

```
img2 = cv2.imread('watermark_no_copy.png')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

My first image to make a mask and its gray map photo

```
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

[image: Gray Mapped img2gray]

After this operation ı make a mask

```
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(img2gray)
```

[image: Gray mapped mask_inv]

My white background

```
white_background = np.full(img2.shape , 255 , dtype= np.uint8)
```

my or operation

```
bk = cv2.bitwise_or(white_background,white_background,mask=mask_inv)
```

and ı get the

[image]

ı didn't understand why, also the result i expected is this img while it isn't using in color map

[image: ecpected imag]